# Show bottom of an overflow string in a div with fixed height/width?

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow

**Background**

I have a non-scrollable div with fixed width and height. 
Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Naibaf/47fm4pvf/2/

**Goal**

I want to show as much of a bottom string were it not for the preceding string.

**Reasoning and problem**

Should you ask yourself: Why? I am trying to display a [news-alert-like-bar](http://download.remysharp.com/marquee.html), but I am concatenating the content of my div with `setInterval()` which will make it overflow quickly.

In my judgement, jQuery's `.scrollTop()` like here: http://jsfiddle.net/2WpQf/1/ is ill-suited, because I want my div not to be scrollable. Same goes for CSS `overflow`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

**HTML**

```
<p>How to make the bottom of a string visible within the boundaries of a div and NOT show or hide the top part?</p>
<p>The opposite of what I want:
</p>
<div class="hidden">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.hidden {
background-color: #00FF00;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me  ... You want fixed dimensions, but show all content and don't use scroll?

Comment: Fixed dimensions, no scroll, but show ONLY as much of the bottom content as fits in the div.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/47fm4pvf/3/ ?

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot. How do I give you credit now?

Comment: XD I will post that as an answer  ...

Comment: Generally we use div.hidden {
background-color: #00FF00;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use an extra container and `position:absolute` from the bottom, that way when you add more text the block seems to increase from bottom to top:

```css
div.hidden {
  position:relative;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*Position extrawrap*/
div.hidden span {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden">
  <! -- Extra Wrapper Here -->
  <span>
    You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
  </span>
</div>
```

---

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/47fm4pvf/3/)